# Oracle DB basic informations to be found

Tags: oracle, sas

Sorry for the basic question.
I have Sas automathically connected to a Oracle Database.
I would like to know the host, the port and the information of this database to connect to it from python as well. There is no "tsnnames.ora" file on my pc, how can I do that? Maybe from SaS where I have access to the DB?

Thanks

Comment: @Abra apparently SaS doesnt like the symbol $ in v$instance.
If I use the "from dual" it doesn't know what dual is!

Comment: I've never dealt with SaS, but if it were in this position I would first simply ask the dBA.  Lacking that, I would read up on how to configure SaS to connect to oracle, then use that info drill down into your current configuration and see what it has.

Comment: Dual is present only in Oracle, there isn't a need for it in SAS (or other SQL flavours) there are other ways. You should ask your DB for the relevant connection information so that you're connecting appropriately. You're using cx_oracle?

Comment: If you want to give it a try, open up SAS Enterprise Guide, log in to your SAS server, right-click your Oracle library and click Properties. It should give you some basics about the connection. If not, as others have said, your DBA will be able to tell you.